# Elasticsearch is slow to update mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Elasticsearch has become extremely slow when receiving input from Logstash, particularly when using file input. I have had to wait for 10+ minutes to get results. Oddly enough, standard input is mapped very quickly, which leads me to believe that my config file may be too complex, but it really isn't.

My config file uses file input, my filter is grok with 4 fields, and my output is to Elasticsearch. The file I am inputting is a .txt with 5 lines in it.

Any suggestions? Elasticsearch and Logstash newbie here.

```
input {
     file {
        type => "type"
        path => "insert_path"
        start_position = > "beginning'
          }
}

filter {
    grok { match => {"message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:primary} %{WORD:secondary} %{NUMBER:speed}" } 
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

Thought: Is it a sincedb_path issue? I often try to reparse files without changing the filename.

Comment: Could you give us an example of exactly what you're doing? Your question is pretty broad. Could you post your config file?

Comment: config file posted

Comment: Can you please check the elasticsearch logs once. It should be present in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log